# Regex replacement to remove whitespace between html tags

Tags: java, html, regex, mustache, handlebars.java

I'm currently working with HTML built from a mustache/handlebars template.

The goal is to take the text after handlebars generates it and reduce its size by removing unnecessary whitespace characters, but keeping attribute values and content of tags intact.

Consider the following as an example:

```
</p>                                </td>                            </tr>                            <tr>                                <td>
```

should become:

```
</a></td></tr><tr><td>
```

And:

```
<p align="left"> Untouchable text </p>               </td>            </tr>
```

should become:

```
<p align="left"> Untouchable text </p></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><")` as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "<p align=\"left\"> Untouchable text </p>               </td>            </tr>";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<p align="left"> Untouchable text </p></td></tr>
```

Note:

1. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) to learn more about `String::replaceAll`.
2. The regex, `\\s+`is used to match space(s).